# Submin password reset without e-mail sending

Tags: email, svn

I have installed Submin. Manual says that I should recover my password at the first login. It should be ok, submin will send my new password by e-amil, but e-mail sending is disabled on server. How can I get a new password without e-mail sending in Submin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open your database with sqlite3.

```
sqlite3 /var/lib/submin/conf/submin.db
```

In the tool run these commands:

```
DELETE FROM password_reset WHERE userid = 1;
INSERT INTO password_reset(userid,expires,key) VALUES(1,strftime('%s','now')+(7*24*60*60),'verysecretfakekey');
```

Then, run this sql statement to verify username and email:

```
SELECT name,users FROM users WHERE id = 1;
```

The output will be in the following format:

```
username, email
```

Once done, close sqlite3 and open the following url:

```
http://example.com/submin/password/<username>/key
```

In the default case with these sql statements it should be

```
http://example.com/submin/password/admin/verysecretfakekey
```

Comment: I have tried this, but after I try to login: "Password is not encrypted with MD5, maybe password is not set. "

Comment: Guess they changed the way passwords are generated, did some research and came up with a new method, updated my post.

Comment: After opening the db, second instruction gives an error: Error: unable to open database "/var/lib/submin/conf/submin.db": unable to open database file

Comment: Hmm, I'm guessing your database is at another location or is in use? try finding submin.db on your disk (either check or use find / -type f -name submin.db) or perhaps its currently in use and you need to close programs using it (e.g. maybe webmin has it locked, try seeing if there are any webmin processes or shut down apache temporarely)

Comment: I can open the db file in mcedit. So there is in right place.

Comment: Well, It's most likely opened in another program making sqlite3 unable to write to the file? Check if you have any other programs which have the database open, as submin runs under apache or nginx, I would recommend also to try this with apache or nginx shut down.

Comment: I use only apache, but same error when apache is off.

Comment: Make sure you have write permissions on the database and the directory containing the database and on a file called 'submin-journal). If still getting that error try running sqlite3 as root. (sudo)

Comment: It is OK now, working great!